# Put more than one namespace on group route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.1

I have a default group route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth',]], function(){});
```

I installed a package that has controllers inside another folder, how to add one more namespace so that I can use controller of package inside that group.

This error is showing up

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Waavi\Translation\Repositories\TranslationRepository does not exist
```

This is in my composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: did you try with `['auth','other']` ?

Comment: in your code where are you using controller ?

Comment: how do you mean I'm trying to use it inside route group namespace of controller is Waavi\Translation\Repositories;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Controller with its complete qualified namespace:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth',]], function(){
    Route::get('/','App\Controller1@action1');
    Route::get('/test','OtherNamespace\Controller1@action1');
});
```

Also update your composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Waavi\\Translation\\Repositories\\": "vendor/directory/structure"
     }
},
```

After that run:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: Route::patch('configuration', 'Waavi\Translation\Repositories\TranslationRepository@update'); tried it allready but it's showing error I wrote in the first post

Comment: Waavi\Translation\Repositories\TranslationRepository is not a complete qualified namespace, especially, it's probably a package installed in the vendor. Is that the namespace mentioned in the TranslationRepository class? Did you run composer dumpautoload?

Comment: namespace Waavi\Translation\Repositories; this is namespace used in namespace and i did comoser dumpautoload, and it didn't help

Comment: is the namespace added in the composer.json autoload part?

Comment: I added in the first post what is in my composer.json autoload

Comment: OK, it's missing, you need to add. I will update the answer.

Comment: I did but now the rest of the controllers don't work if i delete the first and add yours

Comment: You need to keep both App and Waavi

Comment: I added comma and put yours but it still showing that the error in the first post

Comment: Do you run composer dumpautoload after each change? Also, did you replace `vendor/directory/structure` with the correct directory, as that depends on the package, and I do not know it.

Comment: /waavi/translation/src/Repositories is the structure to this but it always tries to look from  App\Http\Controllers\